# Geth on Windows: Does my keystore need to be in blockchain directory?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I've noticed some weird behavior using Geth. My setup is that I am running Geth 1.7.3 with this command:

```
geth.exe --cache=1024 --rpc --datadir "C:\data\ethereum_blockchain"
```

Then, I start Mist and it connects to Geth just fine. But it does not load my account. My %appdata%/Ethereum directory is present with my Keystore inside it.

When I copied the keystore directory to C:\data\ethereum_blockchain\keystore, then Mist loaoded my wallet.

Is this expected? Have I been misunderstanding what --datadir is suppoosed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior is to assume the keystore is inside your data directory. But geth have an option to allow setting different paths for each

> geth --datadir *DATA_DIR* --keystore *KEYSTORE_DIR*

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. So if I just use "geth --datadir xx", then load Mist and create a new wallet, my keystore would be in the xx directory? Not that I uh, lost a keystore or anything..

Comment: Yes, using `--datadir` will only search for your keystore in the new directory. Your previous keystore should still be intact inside %AppData%\Ethereum (but always make a backup copy).